# Math Grouping Optimization

Tags: optimization, algorithms, puzzle, discrete-optimization, set-partition

I have roughly 10 employees assigned a random cost (for this example, lets say $0-$500). I'm trying to optimize grouping the employees into 3 groups. Every employee in the group must be paid the same amount, the highest cost of the employee in that group. There is no requirement for how many employees in each group.

Example table;

| Employee | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 400 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 420 |
| 7 | 80 |
| 8 | 180 |
| 9 | 270 |
| 10 | 410 |

Example Non-Optimized Solution)

**Group 1**
Employees 4, 5, 2 (Cost 30 based on employee 2 costing $10)

**Group 2**
Employees 7, 1 (Cost 240 based on employee 1 costing $120)

**Group 3**
Employees 8, 9, 3, 10, 6 (Cost 2100 based on employee 6 costing $420)

**Total Cost** = $2,370

Any advice on how to break down this problem greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a requirement on how many people need to be in each group?

Comment: No requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing whatsoever to do with *group theory*, which is a branch of abstract mathematics dealing with symmetries, transformations, and such.

Anyway, the way to visualize your problem is as follows:

[image]

You search through the two "splitting positions" to minimize the combined area of the three colored rectangles (total cost).

I wonder if the following pseudo-greedy algorithm is optimal:

- Assign the initial partitions above employee 1 and above employee 9.
- Compute the total cost.
- Take a step up (for the lower partition threshold);  Separately, take a step down (for the higher partition threshold);  Choose which of those two steps leads to the smallest new total cost.
- Repeat the above operation until neither proposed step reduces the total cost.
- Terminate

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the visualization! Appreciate it. Sorry to have worded the problem category incorrectly.

Comment: Works well fore now! It's a great starting point for me, I really appreciate your insight. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Without too much additional effort, you can make this into an exact algorithm by using dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using an optimization solver with binary variables $ x_{e,g}= 1$ if employee $e$ is assigned to group $g=\{1,2,3\}$, else 0 and a continuous variable $0 \le K_g$ that represents the cost.
So define objective to minimize $\sum_g K_g $ with constraints
$\sum_g x_{e,g}= 1 \quad \forall e $
$ 1\le \sum_e x_{e,g} \quad \forall g$
$ c_{e}x_{e,g} \le K_g \quad \forall e \ \ \forall g$ where $c_e$ is given cost of an employee $e$
The last constraint captures the highest cost of employee in the group.

Comment: There's no summation in that last constraint.

Comment: @TickaJules Yes that's right, thanks.

Comment: Your formulation counts only the cost of the most expensive employee in each group (the heights of the rectangles instead of the areas).